# How to clone existing ember.js projects from Github repository and run into you local machine?

Tags: github, ember.js, npm, localhost, npm-install

After installing Git, Node.js, Bower, Ember Cli and Phantoms Js into my local machine. I do the 
following steps.

```
> git clone <repository-url> sample  // in this case sample is a new repository in my local machine
> cd sample 
> npm install
> bower install
```

So, after that, when i enter this command: ember server

It says that i am missing some dependencies. Do you know how to generally clone any public `ember.js` projects from Github account and run into your machine?

Comment: Please can you provide the full error message including any details of the missing dependencies. Those will make it easier to help. If the repo is a public repo, it would also help if you were to tell us which one so that we can see if there are any specific issues with that repo.

Comment: Those steps should work (and you shouldn't need bower install for later 2.x and 3.x versions). Try a project you know to be good, maybe creating a new ember app via EmberCLI, pushing it to your Github account, and then trying to clone it into a new folder and seeing if it'll run for you. If not, it could be you have some bad versions of dependencies cached locally, look into clearing your NPM cache.